# Encrypt Password in Android and verify it wit PHP / Yii

Tags: php, android, encryption, yii

I use Yii Framework in PHP, and to encrypt password in database, I use :

```
$pass = CPasswordHelper::hashPassword ($this->newPassword);
```

To verify password match, I use :

```
    if (!CPasswordHelper::verifyPassword($this->currentPassword,$this->_user->passwd)) {
...
    }
```

Now, I have to send encrypted password from Android device.
I should send it without encryptation and process it with PHP, but it doesn't seem so secure send clean password.

So, is there a way in Android to encrypt pass the same way CPasswordHelper does????
[ The thing is I don't really know exactly what encryptation / hash is applied in PHP ]

Any Help will be appreciated!

Tx

Comment: ok.. encrypt password in android and send it..to server. this is what you want ?

Comment: So long as you are using ssl, you should be fine sending the unencrypted password to the server.

Comment: Yes, but in the same way I do it in PHP with Yii. I should Encrypt it with SHA1.Sha1Hash, but I guess it is not the same encryptation that  CPasswordHelper::hashPassword  so CPasswordHelper::verifyPassword will fail

Comment: For what it's worth Yii's CPasswordHelper is using blowfish (http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php -> see CRYPT_BLOWFISH)

Comment: I'm seeing that there is no native way ( or simple way ) to do it, and I have SSL Cert, so I should not need to encrypt pass as @CJWurtz says.